# Removing a GPU from Existing Virtual Machine in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I am trying to remove a GPU from a Virtual Machine in Google Cloud. Right now the VM is set as an A2 Series, but I'd like to switch to a GPU-free E2 machine.

I have been following the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/add-remove-gpus#remove-gpu), however the Edit VM interface will not allow me to "x" out GPUs or to select less than one GPU.

As a result I keep getting this error when attempting to switch to an E2:

```
Operation type [setMachineResources] failed with message "Accelerator optimized instances must be attached with A100 GPUs."
```

---

**After attempts at fixing...**

Following @Ferregina Pelona's answers, if I try running the following from the cloud shell:

```
gcloud compute instances set-machine-type INSTANCE_NAME --zone=ZONE --machine-type=e2-micro
```

Then I get the following error:

```
- e2 instances do not support onHostMaintenance=TERMINATE unless they are preemptible.
```

However the GUI also throws a bug if I try to change onHostMaintenance to `migrate` there.

If I try to change it from the command line (Thanks @Ferregina for your suggestions!):

```
gcloud compute instances set-scheduling INSTANCE_NAME --zone=ZONE  --maintenance-policy=MIGRATE
```

Then I get the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.set-scheduling) Could not fetch resource:  - Instances with guest accelerators do not support live migration.
```

Is there any way to `set-machine-type` and `set-scheduling` simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

There is some kind of glitch with the UI when changing from the A-series to a "normal" instance so you may want to report this [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187134&template=0). Being more specific, is about the request the UI sends to the GCE API which seems to contain the new intance type but also the GPU; this is not a valid configuration.

As a workaround may want to change the instance type using the [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/set-machine-type) command:

`gcloud compute instances set-machine-type INSTANCE_NAME --zone=ZONE --machine-type=e2-micro`

**EDIT**

Because the `gcloud` commands are not useful because the operations are split (IMO a very bad design of the commands), you may want to go with these [steps](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/update-instance-properties#update). Those basically download the configuration file for the instance, then change the instance type and the scheduling and apply the changes.

Comment: Thank you so much Ferregina! Do I type this command in the cloud shell? Or in an ssh terminal of the VM?

Comment: In the Cloud Shell. Remember that before changing the type of the instance you should first stop it

Comment: thank you for the clarification! When I run the command in the cloud shell, I get the following error: " - e2 instances do not support onHostMaintenance=TERMINATE unless they are preemptible."

Comment: You need to change the onHostMaintenance to migrate. I'd suggest to create a new question for follow up questions and the documentation since the focus of this one is to change from A-series to E2

Comment: Thanks Ferregina! This won't allow me to change to E2, because of the onHostMaintenance which I'm unable to change in the GUI. Is there a way to change that from the command line along with your answer? It appears that I cannot switch to E2 unless these happen simultaneously.

Comment: Use `gcloud compute instances set-scheduling INSTANCE_NAME --zone=ZONE  --maintenance-policy=MIGRATE` this is on https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/set-scheduling

Comment: Thanks again! These don't seem to work separate from each other. If I do this, then I get the following error: `ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.set-scheduling) Could not fetch resource:
 - Instances with guest accelerators do not support live migration.` Is there a way to do these simultaneously? I'll edit the question to reflect the extended issue.

Comment: Yes, I suppose that could happen :/. I'm going to edit the answer

Answer (score 1):

per this [public document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance) "If your VM does not have a local SSD and is not part of a managed instance group (MIG), you can change the machine type of your VM after stopping it."

And then checking at the [Machine family comparison](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#machine_type_comparison), looks like machine family A2 uses local SSD therefore it could not be possible because if your VM has a local SSD, you cannot stop the VM to change its machine type unless you force it to stop, which causes you to lose all of the data on the local SSD.

Answer (score 1):

It actually may be easiest to delete your Instance and create a new one. Stopping an instance actually deletes the VM, so there should be little difference.

If you need to keep you persistent disks, then you can mark them as autoDelete=false, and attach to the new Instance on creation. If you need to keep your IP, then you can create a reservation in a similar fashion.